# Call a javascript function dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have some functions defined inside a array like this.

```
checkInputType : function(sel){
 alert($(sel).prop('type'));
},
checkSelect : function(el){
 .......
},
.....
```

And I can call it like this `options.checkInput($(this));`. This is working.

Now I want to call any of those defined functions dynamically. So I have this array with the function names in it.

```
var elmType2Func = {'input' : 'checkInput', 'select' : 'checkSelect', 'textarea' : 'checkTextarea'};
```

Now looping through all elements inside a form I want to call the right function for each element(**elmType2Func** array with **element as a key** and **function name as a value**).

```
var element = $(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
```

I cannot call like this - `options.elmType2Func[element]($(this));` 
I know this is not the right way to call this function. 
 Can anybody help me with this.

Comment: Don't you just need to do `options[elmType2Func[element]]($(this));` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store functions, not their names:

```
var elmType2Func = {'input' : checkInput, 'select' : checkSelect, 'textarea' : checkTextarea};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmb25/

If the functions are already members of some object, like:

```
var options = {
     checkInput: function() {...},
     checkSelect: function() {...},
}
```

then you can keep strings in `elmType2Func`:

```
var elmType2Func = {'input' : 'checkInput', 'select' : 'checkSelect', 'textarea' : 'checkTextarea'};
```

and use double indirection to refer to them:

```
var tag = $(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
var fun = options[elmType2Func[tag]];
```

gives you a reference to the function.

Comment: yes. The functions are already members of options object. Thanks. working perfectly...

Answer (score 2):

Rather than putting a string for the name put the function

```
var elmType2Func = {
    'input' : checkInput,
    'select' : checkSelect, 
    'textarea' : checkTextarea,
    'submit' : function (arg) { ... }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> options.elmType2Func[element]($(this));
> ```

That is accessing the property with the literal name `elmType2Func` on the object - you want to use bracket notation here as well:

```
options[elmType2Func[element]]($(this));
```

---

Alternatively, you might not use `elmType2Func` as a property *name* lookup table, but to look up the functions directly:

```
var elmType2Func = {
    'input' : options.checkInput,
    'select' : options.checkSelect, 
    'textarea' : options.checkTextarea
};
elmType2Func[element]($(this));
```